8 pin SMPS controller chip
I have a 12v 10amp SMPS unit, the main controller ic was damaged and broke apart on removal - hence no markings retrievable.




Is there any way to narrow down to possible matches of the controller chip for tis board?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The pinout matches SG6846A from Fairchild. If you provide a better picture and some component values, a better verification would be possible.
There are two versions of this chip, one with overcurrent latch, which I would try here, and another without.
Update:
The component values visible on the new, better picture match the application circuit in the datasheet of SG6846A as far as I can read them.
R33 looks damaged, it should be in the range of 330 Ω.
Check the big 0.22 Ω shunt R46 and the primary MOSFET, they may also be dead.
And what is this solder mess at the MOSFET pins?
Update 2:
This is the schematic of the primary side of your PCB. As you can see, this perfectly matches the pinout of SG6846A. Pin 1 is GND.


thanks for the prompt revert.

Pin 1 is definitely +Ve, Pin 6 is driver output.  Pin 3 is connected to -ve via R38,42 and 37. Basis this, pinout doesnt match SG6846A .

Thanks, you are right - i made an error reading the PCB tracks.
one other query - this chip is not locally available , how can I identify a substitute ?

There are many functional compatible ICs, but none with the same pinout, as far as I know. You can try NCP12400, NCP1239, NCP1237. Not sure if this work is worth the effort.
